# What is the farthest a spacecraft has traveled away from earth?

Tags: spacecraft

I know there are some awesomely far spacecraft that have been travelling for decades away from earth, but which is the farthest? And has it discovered something amazing?

Comment: Do you mean space-craft in general, or satellites? 
E.g. Voyager is a space-craft. Sputnik was a satellite.

Comment: @Everyone, pretty much.

Comment: @Everyone Voyager is orbiting the milky way isn't it ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Wikipedia states that [Voyager 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_1) is currently farthest from Earth; it gives the distance as of Dec 3 2013 as 126.95 AU ($1.899 \cdot 10^{10}\text{ km}$) from Earth. At that distance, the speed of light delay is approximately 17 hours 36 minutes. By Dec 7 2013 it was listed as at a distance of 127.03 AU from Earth, which means it is moving away from Earth at a speed of 0.02 AU per day, corresponding to a speed (relative to Earth) of roughly 35 km/s. The speed relative to the sun is stated as approximately 17 km/s. The probe was launched, along with its sister [Voyager 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_2), in August 1977; Wikipedia states that Voyager 2's current speed relative to the sun is slightly above 15.4 km/s at a distance from Earth of 103.00 AU as of Dec 7 2013. Since you're asking about the *farthest*, I focus on Voyager 1.

Exactly what might count as "amazing discoveries" is of course a matter of personal opinion rather than a strict scientific assessment, but Voyager 1 does seem to have contributed to [our understanding of the outer limits of the heliosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_1#Interstellar_medium). As [TildalWave](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/49/tildalwave) pointed out in a comment (since deleted), it has also provided evidence of many other things, including that it has:

- Provided evidence of [active volcanoes on celestial bodies other than Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Vulcanic_Explosion_on_Io.jpg)
- Sent us close-up pictures of Saturn's ring system, including detail pictures of [Saturn's F ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Voyager1-saturn-f-ring.jpg)
- Proven to still be working (although [much of the on-board equipment has either been deactivated or malfunctioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_1#Scientific_instruments)) 36 years after launch, and possible to communicate with across such vast distances, and sending useful scientific data [having exited the solar system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_1#Exit_from_the_heliosphere); it is expected to remain operational until some time around 2025, for a nearly 50 years long active service life, whereas [Voyager 2 is expected to remain operational until around 2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_2#Power) for 40-45 years of service
- Sent us the ["Pale Blue Dot"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pale_Blue_Dot.png) picture, showing Earth [from 6.4 billion km](http://www.planetary.org/explore/space-topics/earth/pale-blue-dot.html) (42.8 AU) away

[The feat of communicating with the spacecraft](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13227/14091) ([also here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/958/415)) might actually be quite significant in and of itself; Voyager 1 communicates with Earth (through the Deep Space Network) on [frequencies near 2.3 GHz and 8.4 GHz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_1#Communication_system). Unless I'm getting the calculations wrong (although the numbers do appear to be within the ballpark), [free space propagation losses alone](https://ham.stackexchange.com/a/353/29) is in the neighborhood of 300 dB on 2.3 GHz and 320 dB on 8.4 GHz. Communications with Voyager [is done](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9824/415) with about 20 kW uplink into the DSN's large antennas.

Comment: Wouldn't the speed relative to Earth depend on the day? It would cycle + and - 30k/s in a sinusoidal pattern over the course of a year.

Comment: @JDługosz It probably does, just as you say. Notice I did include the speed relative to the Sun as well.

Comment: I know...I was confused as to the relationship between the two.

Comment: Perhaps the question might be: "being the most distant (from Earth) still-functioning probe (at least partially), what meaningful contributions to science is it continuing to make?" - to which the answer appears lie in the data it has collected/is collecting about the heliopause and interstellar medium.

Answer (score 5):

As of 7 February:

> Voyager 1 Spacecraft, ephemeris for Fri 7 February 2014, 02:13 UTC
>   Right Ascension: 17h 11m 54s Declination: +12° 01’ 12” (J2000) [HMS|00:00:00|Dec]
>   Distance from Sun: 18,968.76 Million Km Distance from Earth: 19,024.36 Million Km
>   Magnitude: N.A. Constellation: Oph

given an AU as 149.597 million km... 127.1 AU and climbing. Note that distance will vary by ±2 AU over the year, and is travelling about 1AU per 100.5 days, or about 3.6 AU per year.

http://theskylive.com/ephemerides-computation?obj=voyager1#lat|77.9799442515|lon|102.02461516200002|fov|80