# Antenna required to reach titan

Tags: power, antenna, data-transmission, titan

There are two 12U cubesats, one in Earth orbit and one in orbit around Titan. They have a transmit power of 700 W (for short periods) and have identical antennas.

What diameter and what type of antenna would be advised so that these spacecraft can communicate with each other?

Comment: Not a radio tech here: but the prelimenary answer is easy: "Insufficient data, no receiving antenna size specified."

Comment: the same diameter, the connection is Satellite <-> Satellite the same, one in Titan orbit and other in LEO

Comment: @ValentinoZaffrani I made an edit to clarify and include your reply in comments. How does this look?

Comment: What is the expected data rate? Kilobits per second, bits per second, bits per minute or hour?

Comment: Kilobits per second

Comment: This question is deeply flawed. You are not going to do this with two 12U cubesats, as you have already been told in the highly related question [X-Band range and data](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/41909/x-band-range-and-data).

Comment: The higher the data rate you expect the lower the possibility of a solution. Kilobits per second have been done using a very large DSN antenna with a very powerful transmitter.