# Most far away location reached thus far

Tags: spacecraft, space-shuttle, deep-space

So far, what is the furthest space exploration machines have been able to reach in the universe? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://space.stackexchange.com/q/3010/265 .

Comment: Thanks, I did not know Voyager one from 1977 was still around.