# Which is the longest distance traveled by a space craft?

Tags: spacecraft, travel, long-duration

Which is the longest distance traveled by a space craft? Manned or unmanned? I believe it's Voyager, but I am not sure about the distance it traveled or is still traveling.

I believe the mission would be a one way mission obviously, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Distance travelled relative to what?  We're all travelling tremendous distances relative to the Sun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spacecraft [farthest away from Earth](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/what-is-the-farthest-a-spacecraft-has-traveled-away-from-earth) is Voyager 1. But that's not necessarily the longest distance traveled. If you accept the distance traveled while in orbit, a spacecraft can rack up a lot of miles while staying close to Earth.

Let's try this for Helios I:
launched in 1974, so 42 years ago. 367.920 hours, 1.324 *10<sup>9</sup> seconds, at 45 km/s this is 59 *10<sup>9</sup> km traveled, much further than Voyager's 19 *10<sup>9</sup> km.

The Helios probes are in an eccentric probe. Assuming a speed of 70 km/s at perihelion and 30 km/s at aphelion (close to Earth's speed), a straight average is 45 km/s.
A better value can be calculated by finding its orbital period and the length of one orbit, I'm having some trouble figuring out how to find that length.

Comment: Speed record actually now belongs to Juno, which at the time of Jupiter intercept achieved 73 km/s.

Comment: Yes, but that's not useful for this calculation: with its highly elliptical orbit, Juno will be traveling slower than that most of the time.

Comment: Helios was also quite eccentric, so... By that measure, your time is off, it will spend far more time at a slower speed. The speed you listed was the highest achieved, at the point closest to the sun, the furthest point will be much slower.

Comment: changed the calculation a bit, using an average speed instead of maximum.

Comment: Interesting! I've just asked [When are close approaches of Helios 1 and 2 to the Earth? Any historical tracking data? Any reports in sky surveys?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49188/12102)